# Syntax highlighting stopped working

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

[Json.Net - Serialize property name without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553516/json-net-serialize-property-name-without-quotes) is tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), but it doesn't show any syntax highlighting to me, and the answer isn't showing it either. It seems to be the case for any question I view, such as [Trouble with threads in OSX and Ruby 1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593149/trouble-with-threadsleep-in-osx-and-ruby-1-9-2), which is tagged [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby).

This worked fine for me until recently.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, but it didn't change anything.

It might be related to my upgrade to Firefox 7 (the OS is Win 7 64-bit).

Comment: I don't know when and where syntax highlighting shows up, but not highlighting for me in Safari 5 too.

Comment: The code I see is not highlighted too, and I am using Google Chrome on Mac OS X 10.7. Maybe it's because there are two tags that are associated with different syntax highlightings.

Comment: I've been using FF7 for a while, and syntax highlighting was working fine. However, I can now repro this -- No syntax is highlighting.

Comment: @kiamlaluno It's every question, not just that one.

Comment: @agf I thought that svick was referring only to questions tagged [tag:c#], not to every question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno It now seems to be fixed, but I was able to repro it on Python questions as well. I see the highlighting everywhere now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't ask... this was too weird.

But... fixed.

A **very** genuinely-felt "thank you" for reporting this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but by saying "don't ask" you've made me even more curious.

Comment: So...a bunch of ninjas stole your pet ponies and left riddled clues in the source?

Comment: @Padded something like that, except some *other* ninjas then came and stole the clues

Comment: So it was a "So that's what that code was for!" moment? If yes, I can feel with you...I know those too damn well...

Comment: @Padded it wasn't even a code change!

Comment: Okay, now I'm really curios what happened!

Comment: @Padded and if I ever find out, I'll let you know ;p

Comment: At first I thought the Japanese Stack Exchange was to blame, as there the Ruby tag would probably mean text on top of other text, but no sign of that tag yet!